# Use of empty() and "or" in if statement PHP

Tags: php, if-statement

I'm trying to make an `IF` statement using the function `empty()` and a `||`. I'm not sure the problem is between the operator and the function, but I don't have any leads on anything else.

Each check in the `IF` is working individually.

Here is what I want to do, but I have an error :

```
if(empty($arrayA['somevalue']) || ($x->val1 == 0 && intval($x->valInteger) > 0)){
    $arrayA['somevalue'] = $y;
}
```

The error :

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function *[path]* () in *[path]*/ProductsImporter.php:648 Stack trace: #0

Line 648 is the `IF`

I also tried with `is_numeric()`, but it doesn't change a thing.

My quick fix, which is working fine, but it's so ugly, is this :

```
if(empty($arrayA['somevalue'])){
    $arrayA['somevalue'] = $y;
} else if ($x->val1 == 0 && intval($x->valInteger) > 0){
    $arrayA['somevalue'] = $y;
}
```

Comment: Did you obfiscate the error message or is that ACTUALLY what the error message says?

Comment: Try deleting the whitespace around the `||` operator and then explicitly adding the space back in (i.e. DO NOT simply undo the deletion, but actually type space characters in). It's possible that you have whitespace characters that are actually unicode and thus not being processed correctly. I've run into a similar error once in the past. Ruling this out to start would be a good idea.

Comment: another hint for debugging multiple condtional if statements - break up each condtion on a new line, to narrow down exactly what line number it's referring to. Having a bunch of variables/arrays checks/functions in one if statement makes it a one liner sure, but that's more potential for hidden errros

Comment: @Fleury26 I'm not saying break the conditional up, I literally mean put each condtional on a [new line](https://phpfiddle.tk/a68b10f2)

Comment: @B.Fleming Yup... that was it. I had a similar problem with things like "> 2" before where I needed to get rid of the space before the "2", but never around an "or". Thank you very much

Comment: No problem! I'll go ahead and submit an answer so we can have this question marked as closed. Glad the fixed it! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the discussion in the comments, the problem is a subtle one: the whitespace around the `||` operator turned out to be unicode whitespace characters. PHP thus interpreted the whitespace directly after the `||` operator as the name of a function, resulting in the error.

Replacing the offending whitespace with non-unicode whitespace fixes this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Like @B.Fleming said in the comments, the problem was around the `||`. The characters were, for some reason, not a normal space and were not processed correctly.

Getting rid of the spaces did the job so here is the new line (I get rid of every spaces just in case):

```
if(empty($arrayA['somevalue'])||($x->val1==0&&intval($x->valInteger)>0)){
 $arrayA['somevalue'] = $y;
}
```

For future reference, I use Coda 2 with PhpPlugin 4.2beta and Twig-HTML 0.2. I'm not sure if it's Coda, a module or something else, but that's the info I have.